# Configurable Rijndael implementation for Linux?

Tags: linux, cryptography

I'm trying to recreate an (old) C# program in something that will run on Linux. So far I'm struggling to find an implementation that's configurable enough to make it happen. These are the configuration options:

```
Padding=ISO10126
CipherMode=CBC
KeySize=256
BlockSize=256
IV=(IV goes here)
Key=(Key goes here)
```

It seems OpenSSL and other implementations make assumptions about where the IV is stored and the padding.

For reference on the padding, [look here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.iso10126?view=netframework-4.7).

Ideally it would be a command line utility.

Comment: Well, using the same IV for different messages encrypted with the same key has security issues; are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: @galvatron Perhaps I need to make this more clear. I just need the ability to specify the IV so I can unencrypt it. Many implementations make the assumption that it's hidden in the key or something. Every entry does have its own IV.

Comment: You could always leave it in C# and run it using Mono, which has a RijndaelManaged implementation.

Comment: Interesting @Xander I'll have to look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather specific so I don't think there is a ready made solution. With the right libraries it is however simple to create one.

```
package nl.owlstead.crypto;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RijndaelEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.ISO10126d2Padding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class RijndaelStrangeCLI {

    private static final int RIJNDAEL_256 = 256;
    private static final boolean FOR_ENCRYPTION = true;
    private static final boolean FOR_DECRYPTION = false;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1_024;
    private static final int EOS = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int argOff = 0;

        boolean encryptOrDecrypt;
        String choice = args[argOff++];
        if (choice.matches("(?i)-e")) {
            encryptOrDecrypt = FOR_ENCRYPTION;
        } else if (choice.matches("(?i)-d")) {
            encryptOrDecrypt = FOR_DECRYPTION;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Try either -e or -d");
        }

        byte[] keyData = Hex.decode(args[argOff++]);
        byte[] ivData = Hex.decode(args[argOff++]);
        KeyParameter key = new KeyParameter(keyData);
        ParametersWithIV keyAndIV = new ParametersWithIV(key, ivData);

        RijndaelEngine rijndael = new RijndaelEngine(RIJNDAEL_256);
        ISO10126d2Padding almostPKCS7Padding = new ISO10126d2Padding();
        CBCBlockCipher cbcMode = new CBCBlockCipher(rijndael);
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cbcMode,
                almostPKCS7Padding);
        cipher.init(encryptOrDecrypt, keyAndIV);

        byte[] inBuf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] outBuf = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(BUFFER_SIZE)];
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[argOff++]);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[argOff++])) {
            while (true) {
                int read = fis.read(inBuf);
                if (read == EOS) {
                    break;
                }
                int outLen = cipher.processBytes(inBuf, 0, read, outBuf, 0);
                fos.write(outBuf, 0, outLen);
            }
            int last = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, 0);
            fos.write(outBuf, 0, last);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

Compilation: only requires Java, say Java 8 and the Bouncy Castle provider or lightweight API.

Running:

```
java nl.owlstead.crypto.RijndaelStrangeCLI <"-e" or "-d"> <key in hex> <IV in hex> <input filename> <output filename>
```

Comment: If it didn't exist it exists now.

Answer (score 0):

[BouncyCastle](https://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/symmetric/Rijndael.html) can do Rijdael in Java and C#.